# Custom redirection for Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Wordpress with Contact Form 7. Now, I have been trying to redirect people after submission of form with regards to the package they have selected with radio buttons, below is my radio button code:

[radio Packages id:Packages "Basic - USD 99" "Basic Plus - USD 149" "Standard - USD 199" "Premium - USD 249"]

I want to redirect clients to the payment page (after submission of form) to the respective charging link.

Comment: Please provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your specific link into contact form and in that at the bottom of the page you see Additional settings

In that just pass on_sent_ok:'https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/'

Or if you can go payment process with paypal button just pass your button code in above the additional setting "Messages".

On after the first thank you message "Your message was sent successfully. Thanks." you can paste your paypal button code

Answer (score 0):

In the contact form 7 settings, replace any previous code you had in the ‘Additional Settings’ field with the following:

on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.example.com/thank-you/';"